# Object navigator.mediaDevices is not accessible on mobile chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been working on an application in which I use the object *navigator* to stream my webcam.
It works perfectly on my pc browser, here's the [github](https://github.com/AGSTRANGER/Basic-WebCam-Streamer) link.

However, when I launch the app on my phone it crashes. I kept testing different things until I found-out that for some reason the object *navigator* is not accessible on my mobile browser.

This is how I found-out. I create this function:

```
 logErrors(){
  return(navigator.mediaDevices.toString())
```

}

And I displayed it this way:

```
<h1>{this.logErrors()}</h1>
```

PS: I am using React, if the syntax seems a bit strange.

Anyway, on my pc browser, I get this:

[image]

On my phone browser, I get this error:
[image]

Any idea why mediaDevices is not accessible on my phone browser?

Comment: The browser may require a secure context (an `https://` page)

Comment: @Pointy I think you are right. So am I supposed to secure my application with https ? I am not quite sure how I can do this 'O.o

Answer (score 2):

If you check the API of the MediaDevices in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), they say:

> It returns a Promise that resolves to a MediaStream object. If the
>   user denies permission, or matching media is not available, then the
>   promise is rejected with NotAllowedError or NotFoundError
>   respectively.

and

> If the current document isn't loaded securely, navigator.mediaDevices
>   will be undefined, and you cannot use getUserMedia(). See Security for
>   more information on this and other security issues related to using
>   getUserMedia()

So I'm guess that your application does have a security issue (you should have given access through an https application).

Moreover in [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc?hl=en#public_service_announcements):

> Starting with Chrome 47, getUserMedia() requests are only allowed from
>   secure origins: HTTPS or localhost

Comment: I think you are right. So am I supposed to secure my application with https ? I am not quite sure how I can do this 'O.o

Comment: I'm guessing that depends on which browser application you are using. Some browser does not require a secure connection to allow the usage of the user webcam

Comment: Hey, I have solved the problem. Could you please check-out my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue.
1. Open *package.json* and paste this inside *scripts*:

> "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start"

This should serve the app over https
2. If this gives you this error:

> React app error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure
>   WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over
>   HTTPS

Open

> node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js

And paste this code inside the definition of the *connection*:

```
protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',
```

This is apparently a bug in *react-sripts* that hasn't been solved yet. If https protocol is being used we should use WebSockets over SSL/TLS (WSS) protocol instead of WebSockets (WS). You can learn more about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8079#issuecomment-562373869):